# Ignore null values for $last in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

There are documents in 'account' collection. Some fields may not be declared. Look at this.

```
{ _id: ObjectId(1), price: 5400, product: ObjectId(2), count: 1            }
{ _id: ObjectId(1),              product: ObjectId(2), count: 0, sale: 0.2 }
{ _id: ObjectId(1),              product: ObjectId(2), count: 1            }
```

Using aggregate framework, I want to have last price, last sale and count for a product.
Currently I use this query

```
db.collection('account').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
            _id: '$product',
            count: { $sum: '$count' },
            price: { $last: '$price' }, 
            sale: { $last: '$sale' }
        }
    }
], { allowDiskUse: true }).toArray()
```

But `sale` and `price` fields becomes `null`.
I think, I should use `$project` before `$group`, how do I retain last document's value if current field is null?

Comment: I think this is task that calls for reading the data into your language of choice. Any data-frame library (like `pandas` in python) would handle this trivially

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**
The following pipeline should give you the desired result

```
db.getCollection('account').aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$product',
            fields: [
                { name: { $literal: 'price' }, value: '$price',        count: { $literal: 0 } },
                { name: { $literal: 'sale' },  value: '$sale',         count: { $literal: 0 } },
                { name: { $literal: 'count' }, value: { $literal: 0 }, count: '$count' }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$fields'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'fields.value': {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                product: '$_id',
                field: '$fields.name'
            },
            value: {
                $last: '$fields.value'
            },
            count: {
                $sum: '$fields.count'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$_id.product',
            price: {
                $cond: { if: { $eq: [ '$_id.field', 'price' ] }, then: '$value', else: null }
            },
            sale: {
                $cond: { if: { $eq: [ '$_id.field', 'sale' ] }, then: '$value', else: null }
            },
            count: {
                $cond: { if: { $eq: [ '$_id.field', 'count' ] }, then: '$count', else: 0 }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            price: {
                $max: '$price'
            },
            sale: {
                $max: '$sale'
            },
            count: {
                $sum: '$count'
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

**Explanation**
It first creates a new array with elements per field which contain the field name, field value and count value.
Note that the field `count` is treated special as it should be accumulated instead of getting the last value of it.
So after the first stage documents look like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "price",
            "value" : 5400,
            "count" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "sale",
            "count" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "count",
            "value" : 0.0,
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "price",
            "count" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "sale",
            "value" : 0.2,
            "count" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "count",
            "value" : 0.0,
            "count" : 0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "price",
            "count" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "sale",
            "count" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "count",
            "value" : 0.0,
            "count" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

It then unwinds the array and filters it to get rid of null values, so after stage 2 & 3 documents look like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : {
        "name" : "price",
        "value" : 5400,
        "count" : 0.0
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : {
        "name" : "count",
        "value" : 0.0,
        "count" : 1
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : {
        "name" : "sale",
        "value" : 0.2,
        "count" : 0.0
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : {
        "name" : "count",
        "value" : 0.0,
        "count" : 0
    }
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "fields" : {
        "name" : "count",
        "value" : 0.0,
        "count" : 1
    }
}
```

In the fourth stage the fields' last values and sum of `count` are built. Result looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "product" : "2",
        "field" : "sale"
    },
    "value" : 0.2,
    "count" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "product" : "2",
        "field" : "count"
    },
    "value" : 0.0,
    "count" : 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "product" : "2",
        "field" : "price"
    },
    "value" : 5400,
    "count" : 0.0
}
```

As the values are now in separate documents with a different shape than our desired result should be, we need to project them back into something we can eventually group. So in after the fifth stage documents are like so:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "count" : 0.0,
    "price" : null,
    "sale" : 0.2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "count" : 2,
    "price" : null,
    "sale" : null
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "count" : 0.0,
    "price" : 5400,
    "sale" : null
}
```

The final stage then just aggregates those documents per product.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution does in three queries.

```
1. - Group by `product` and sum `count` field
   - Remove any entries, where `count` is 0 and lower
   - Hold `_ids` array as `product_ids`
   - Hold result array as `firstArray`

2. - Match any entries, where 
            - `sale` is 0 and greater
            - `_id` is in `product_ids`
   - Group by `product` and get last `sale` field
   - Hold result array as `secondArray`

3. - Match any entries, where
            - `price` is 0 and greater
            - `_id` is in `product_ids`
   - Group by `product` and get last `price` field
   - Enumerate `firstArray` and add `count` field to entries
   - Enumerate `secondArray` and add `sale` field to entries
```

And the code

```
let firstArray
let secondArray
let product_ids
Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return db.collection(ACCOUNT).aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$product',
                count: { $sum: '$count' }
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                count: { $gt: 0 }
            }
        }
    ], { allowDiskUse: true }).toArray()
}).then(function (array) {
    firstArray = array
    product_ids = array.map(function (item) {
        return item._id
    })
    return db.collection(ACCOUNT).aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                product: { $in: product_ids },
                sale: { $gte: 0 }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$product',
                sale: { $last: '$sale' }
            }
        }
    ], { allowDiskUse: true }).toArray()
}).then(function (array) {
    secondArray = array

    return db.collection(ACCOUNT).aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                product: { $in: product_ids },
                price: { $gte: 0 }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$product',
                price: { $last: '$price' }
            }
        }
    ], { allowDiskUse: true }).toArray()
}).then(function (array) {
    req.data = array.map(function (item) {
        let count = 0
        let sale = 0
        firstArray.some(function (_item) {
            if (item._id.toHexString() == _item._id.toHexString()) {
                count = _item.count
                return true
            }

            return false
        })
        secondArray.some(function (_item) {
            if (item._id.toHexString() == _item._id.toHexString()) {
                sale = _item.sale
                return
            }
            return false
        })

        item.count = count
        item.sale = sale
        return item
    })
    next()
})
```